# Update and remove item in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

when make edit to array list by popup windows or remove item by long click

it just update and remove last value 
arraylist and adapter and listview not updated together
this is my code:

CustomListViewAapter.java

```
package com.zoom.plumbingcalculation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public static final String colFrom="From";
public static final String colTo="To";
public static final String colCFM="CFM";
public static final String colDia="Dia";
public static final String colLength="Length";
public static final String colTotLoss="Loss";
public static final String colDP="DP";

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;
TextView txtFrom;
TextView txtTo;
TextView txtCFM;
TextView txtDia;
TextView txtLength;
TextView txtTotLoss;
TextView txtDP;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String,          String>> list){
    super();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {

    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, null);

        txtFrom=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.From);
        txtTo=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.To);
        txtCFM=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CFM);
        txtDia=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Dia);
        txtLength=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Length);
        txtTotLoss=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TotLoss);
        txtDP=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DP);

    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    txtFrom.setText(map.get(colFrom));
    txtTo.setText(map.get(colTo));
    txtCFM.setText(map.get(colCFM));
    txtDia.setText(map.get(colDia));
    txtLength.setText(map.get(colLength));
    txtTotLoss.setText(map.get(colTotLoss));
    txtDP.setText(map.get(colDP));

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Activity.java

```
package com.zoom.plumbingcalculation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static com.zoom.plumbingcalculation.CustomListViewAdapter.colCFM;
import static com.zoom.plumbingcalculation.CustomListViewAdapter.colDP;
import static com.zoom.plumbingcalculation.CustomListViewAdapter.colDia;
import static com.zoom.plumbingcalculation.CustomListViewAdapter.colFrom;
import static com.zoom.plumbingcalculation.CustomListViewAdapter.colLength;
import static com.zoom.plumbingcalculation.CustomListViewAdapter.colTo;
import static com.zoom.plumbingcalculation.CustomListViewAdapter.colTotLoss;



public class ps_ss_compressed_air extends Activity {

//Compressed Air Variable
private ImageButton CAButAdd;
private ListView CALvDataTable;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> CALvDataTableListItems;
private CustomListViewAdapter CALvDataTableAdapter;

//Compressed Air Popup Add Variable
private LayoutInflater layoutAddInflater;
private View popupAddView;
private PopupWindow popupAddWindow;

private Button CAPAButAdd;
private Button CAPAButCancel;
private Spinner CAPASpDia;
private EditText CAPATxtFrom;
private EditText CAPATxtTo;
private EditText CAPATxtCFM;
private EditText CAPATxtLength;

//Compressed Air Popup Edit Variable
private LayoutInflater layoutEditInflater;
private View popupEditView;
private PopupWindow popupEditWindow;

private Button CAPEButEdit;
private Button CAPEButCancel;
private Spinner CAPESpDia;
private EditText CAPETxtFrom;
private EditText CAPETxtTo;
private EditText CAPETxtCFM;
private EditText CAPETxtLength;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ps_ss_compressed_air);

    //Compressed Air Variable
    CAButAdd = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.CAButAdd);
    CALvDataTable =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.CALvDataTable);

    CALvDataTableListItems= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    CALvDataTableAdapter=new CustomListViewAdapter(this, CALvDataTableListItems);
    CALvDataTable.setAdapter(CALvDataTableAdapter);

    CAButAdd.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            layoutAddInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            popupAddView = layoutAddInflater.inflate(R.layout.ps_ss_compressed_air_popup_add, null);
            //popupView.setAlpha(0.5F);
            popupAddView.setAlpha(1);
            popupAddWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupAddView,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            CAPAButAdd = (Button)popupAddView.findViewById(R.id.CAPAButAdd);
            CAPAButCancel = (Button)popupAddView.findViewById(R.id.CAPAButCancel);
            CAPASpDia = (Spinner) popupAddView.findViewById(R.id.CAPASpDia);
            CAPATxtFrom = (EditText) popupAddView.findViewById(R.id.CAPATxtFrom);
            CAPATxtTo = (EditText) popupAddView.findViewById(R.id.CAPATxtTo);
            CAPATxtCFM = (EditText) popupAddView.findViewById(R.id.CAPATxtCFM);
            CAPATxtLength = (EditText) popupAddView.findViewById(R.id.CAPATxtLength);

            CAPAButAdd.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//Add--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<>();
                    temp.put(colFrom, CAPATxtFrom.getText().toString());
                    temp.put(colTo, CAPATxtTo.getText().toString());
                    temp.put(colCFM, CAPATxtCFM.getText().toString());
                    temp.put(colDia, CAPASpDia.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    temp.put(colLength, CAPATxtLength.getText().toString());
                    temp.put(colTotLoss, "");
                    temp.put(colDP, "");
                    CALvDataTableListItems.add(temp);
                    CALvDataTableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    popupAddWindow.dismiss();
                }});

            CAPAButCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupAddWindow.dismiss();
                }});

            //popupWindow.showAsDropDown(CAButAdd, 50, 50);
            popupAddWindow.showAtLocation(popupAddView, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            popupAddWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupAddWindow.update();

        }});

    CALvDataTable.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,  View view, final int position, long id)
        {
            layoutEditInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            popupEditView = layoutEditInflater.inflate(R.layout.ps_ss_compressed_air_popup_edit, null);
            popupEditView.setAlpha(1);
            popupEditWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupEditView,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            CAPEButEdit = (Button)popupEditView.findViewById(R.id.CAPEButEdit);
            CAPEButCancel = (Button)popupEditView.findViewById(R.id.CAPEButCancel);
            CAPESpDia = (Spinner) popupEditView.findViewById(R.id.CAPESpDia);
            CAPETxtFrom = (EditText) popupEditView.findViewById(R.id.CAPETxtFrom);
            CAPETxtTo = (EditText) popupEditView.findViewById(R.id.CAPETxtTo);
            CAPETxtCFM = (EditText) popupEditView.findViewById(R.id.CAPETxtCFM);
            CAPETxtLength = (EditText) popupEditView.findViewById(R.id.CAPETxtLength);


            HashMap<String, String> temp=CALvDataTableListItems.get(position);
            CAPETxtFrom.setText(temp.get(colFrom));
            CAPETxtTo.setText(temp.get(colTo));
            CAPETxtCFM.setText(temp.get(colCFM));
            CAPESpDia.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)CAPESpDia.getAdapter()).getPosition(temp.get(colDia)));
            CAPETxtLength.setText(temp.get(colLength));

            CAPEButEdit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//Edit-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    HashMap<String,String> temp= CALvDataTableListItems.get(position);
                    temp.put(colFrom, CAPETxtFrom.getText().toString());
                    temp.put(colTo, CAPETxtTo.getText().toString());
                    temp.put(colCFM, CAPETxtCFM.getText().toString());
                    temp.put(colDia, CAPESpDia.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    temp.put(colLength, CAPETxtLength.getText().toString());
                    temp.put(colTotLoss, "");
                    temp.put(colDP, "");
                    CALvDataTableListItems.set(position,temp);
                    CALvDataTableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    popupEditWindow.dismiss();
                }});

            CAPEButCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupEditWindow.dismiss();
                }});

            //popupWindow.showAsDropDown(CAButEdit, 50, 50);
            popupEditWindow.showAtLocation(popupEditView, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            popupEditWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupEditWindow.update();



            //Toast.makeText(ps_ss_compressed_air.this, Integer.toString(position+1) + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    CALvDataTable.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            CALvDataTableListItems.remove(position);
            CALvDataTableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(ps_ss_compressed_air.this,"Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

custom_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/From"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/To"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/CFM"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/Dia"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/Length"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TotLoss"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/DP"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/CAappbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/CAtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:title="@string/app_name">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/Compressed_Air_Name"
            android:id="@+id/CALabCAName"
            android:layout_weight="7"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/CAButAdd"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ps_ss_compressed_air_but_add"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CAappbar"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCAHeader">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:divider="#000000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Nodes_Lab"
            android:id="@+id/CALabNodes"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/Nodes_From_Lab"
                    android:id="@+id/CALabFrom"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/Nodes_To_Lab"
                    android:id="@+id/CALabTo"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CFM_Lab"
            android:id="@+id/CALabCFM"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Diameter_Lab"
            android:id="@+id/CALabDia"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Length_Lab"
            android:id="@+id/CALabLength"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Total_Loss_Lab"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/CALabTotLoss"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Pressure_Drop_Lab"
            android:id="@+id/CALabDP"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutCAHeader"
android:id="@+id/CALvDataTable"
android:longClickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```